# Display post thumbnail after clicking on post id with AJAX

Tags: ajax, post-thumbnails

I want to display post thumbnails after a user clicks on a link in the WordPress loop.

Each post contains the following markup:

```
<span class="id_53">Display Post Image</span>
```

When a user clicks on this `<span>` tag, I want to display the post thumbnail image using AJAX `$.post()` inside of the following markup:

```
<div id="img_in"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by trying this.

**1.** Change this `<span class="id_53">Display Post Image</span>` 

 to `<span class="id_53" data-id="53">Display Post Image</span>`

**2.** Create you js file

```
$(function () {
    // click event example
    $('.id_53').on('click', getThumb);

    // call the ajax
    function getThumb() {
        $.post( 'http://path/wp-content/themes/your-theme/ajax-file.php' , 'my_id='+$(this).attr('data-id') , showThumb );
    }

    // get image source
    function showThumb(e) {
        $('#img_in').style({'background-image':e});
    }

});
```

**3.** Create your ajax-file.php

```
// for external files
include( '../../../wp-load.php' );

// get your variable
$my_id = intval( $_POST['my_id'] );

// get thumbnail ID
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $my_id );

// get path of thumbnail
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'full' );
echo $img[0];
```